# Magic suggest case insensitivity

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5.4, magicsuggest

I need help,

here is my **view**

```
  <div class="hash_field">
     <label for="category_id">Service Hashtags <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
     <input type="text" name="hashtags[]" value="{{ json_encode(old('hashtags'))}}" id="magicsuggest"/>
  </div>
```

and the **magicsuggest** script,

```
<link href="{{ url('plugins/suggestionbox/magicsuggest-min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var ms = $('#magicsuggest').magicSuggest({
            data: '{{route("services.get_array")}}',
            valueField: 'hashtag',
            displayField: 'hashtag',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            hideTrigger: true,
            placeholder: 'Service Hashtags',
            noSuggestionText: '',
            maxSelection: null,
            required: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

here my issue is,
All is working good but i need to get one more functionality
i need plugin to have **case-insensitivity**.
Means that if i add tag like `admin`
Then the plugin should **disallow** me to add `Admin`,`ADMIN`,`AdMiN`
All the possibilities.

[image]

I hope you understand what i want to say.
Thanks in Advance.

This plugin I had used [Magic Suggest](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/)

Comment: Never used the plugin, but a quick look  at the documentation suggests there's a matchCase parameter, have you tried playing with that?

Comment: yup i had checked all of that plugins, methods and all.

Comment: But there is no option for case sensitivity and case insensitivity of tags.

Comment: You could convert the current tags to `.toLowerCase()` as well as the tag you're inputting and check if they're the same `adding === current`?

Comment: umm thats nice but i am searching for if plugin have any method that checks for the same.